# micropython and sys.implementation- different on XIAO SAMD21 and XIAO RP2040

Tags: micropython, samd21

I was working with micropython on a SEEED XIAO (SAMD21) using version 1.18, and wanted to use 'compiled' libraries (`.mpy`) to conserve space.  I had mpy-cross for version 5 which worked okay for me.  I also wanted to have floating point so I built a new micropython with that option- from the latest (20220302) github version- and noticed that mpy-cross had updated to version 6.  I thought I would check to see which versions of `.mpy` were used  The micropython documentation suggests some code to check the version of `.mpy`  using the `sys.implementation` object.  I noticed a variety of `sys.implementation` implementations.

Version 1.18- released by micropython 20220117 on the XIAO SAMD21 gave the following results:

```
MicroPython v1.18 on 2022-01-17; Seeed Xiao with SAMD21G18A
Type "help()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.implementation
('micropython', (1, 18, 0))
>>> type(sys.implementation)
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

This returned a tuple with 2 items- the name  and a tuple with the version info.  But no information on the `mpy` version.

I then tried the released 1.18 version for the RP2040 NANO (and ran it on my XIAO RP2040):

```
MPY: soft reboot
MicroPython v1.18 on 2022-01-17; Raspberry Pi Pico with RP2040
Type "help()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.implementation
(name='micropython', version=(1, 18, 0), mpy=5637)
>>> type(sys.implementation)
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Here the result returned is tuple with 3 attributes- named attributes- and a `mpy` version (5637 & 0xff = 5).  I then recompiled micropython using the `#define MICROPY_PERSISTENT_CODE_LOAD (1)` option to try and match the RP2040 output:

```
MPY: soft reboot
MicroPython v1.18-169-g665f0e2a6-dirty on 2022-03-02; Seeed Xiao with SAMD21G18A
Type "help()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.implementation
('micropython', (1, 18, 0), 6)
>>> type(sys.implementation)
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Now a tuple with 3 items is returned with the `mpy` version (6), but not a named tuple, and no extra data with the `mpy` version.

My question is how can I get consistent results in my XIAO SAMD2 implementation?  Which option should I include or exclude?  Or should I not worry it?  I am studying whether to switch to Python or stay with C(++) for this small processor - leaning to C(++).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use precompiled/bytecode .mpy files then you will need to
Decide to use either bytecode or compile to native code for your mcu platforms.

For bytecode you will need to distribute a bytecode version that matches the runtime firmware, 1.12-1.18 == 5, next version will increase

For native code you'll need to distribute versions for each platform that you want to support.
An esp32c3 cannot run stm32 native code and vice-versa

Also the different ports/board will indeed have differences in some of the stdlib APIs. Your code must be robust enough to handle these differences.

Comment: Thank you for the comments - they address part of my question.   It seems you are saying the implemention of the `sys` lib will vary between ports &or boards - in particular the type of `sys.implementation` .  I will of course check to make sure versions are compatible.

Comment: Correct, there will be subtle differences between ports of the same micropython version. AFAIK there is no conclusive documentation on this, however you could check the firmware stubs located at  https://github.com/Josverl/micropython-stubs to find some differences